# Unpublish blog content after a certain time

Tags: nodes

I have blog content (created with the Blog module). I want to create an archive which has 30 days of time. After that when we click on archive it will unpublish the blog content. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

https://drupal.org/project/scheduler

> This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified
>   dates.
>
> Dates can be entered either as plain text or with calendar popups. To
>   use calendar popups you need to install the Date Popup module, which
>   is part of the Date module.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/scheduler) modules does just that. If you end up having more advanced requirements, leveraging the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module with its Rules Scheduler sub-module could be a good option to go with.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of another two approaches for this. One is to use the module [Node Expire](https://drupal.org/project/node_expire) and let it unpublish or notify users upon expiration.

Another approach. more manual, is to use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) with [Views Bluk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). You create a view with all nodes having post or update date before 30 days and you perform a bulk operation to unpublish them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scheduler module: https://drupal.org/project/scheduler it can both publish and unpublish nodes at a set time or age.

If you want to do it manually, you can unpublish content from the standard drupal content list at admin/content, or you could look into the views bulk operations module (https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). That would allow you to perform actions on content from a views list so you can filter your content to only show content older than the 30 days.

As another option you could look at learning rules and create an unpublish rule. The best rules tutorial I know of is at the Node One learning Library.

Comment: Rules tutorial in the Learning Library is at: http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework